# Access submenu in Selenium using c#

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to access a submenu in selenium using c#. On my the website that I am testing the mouseover to the menu opens another submenu1,mouseover to submenu1 options open submenu2. I want to click on one of the submenu2 options. I tried to run below, everytime it throws an error of element not visible on      custonboarding.Click();

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

var hoverover = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("menu1"));
builder.MoveToElement(hoverover).Build().Perform();

var hoverover1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("submenu1));
builder.MoveToElement(hoverover1).Build().Perform();

var custonboarding = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("submenu2"));
custonboarding.Click();
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Can you just share the site?

Comment: When you watch the script execute, do you see the submenus opening? If the wait suggested in Guy's answer below isn't working, then you probably aren't hovering the right element or something. Hard to tell without seeing the site.

Comment: Hey @JeffC, it is working. Just updated the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might take some time for the element to fully load. You can use explicit wait and `ExpectedConditions` to wait for the element to be visible

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement custonboarding = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("submenu2")));
custonboarding.Click();
```

This will wait up to 5 seconds for the element to be visible.

Comment: I got an error. The driver timed out after 5 seconds. Do you think it has something to do with the Xpath?

Comment: @AmberO Is there something covering the dropdown?

Comment: your answer worked. I think it was taking more time to load. Increased the time.